# Iterate over data frame and create a text file

Tags: python, string, loops

I want to create multiple line items for the agreement number. As you can see below i have used only agreement number[0] to print first data from dental_df[Agreement_number]
But i want to take all the items in the agreement number to be printed.
if i take that whole column def **str** gives me an error
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ljust'
can anybody help me. I am missing something

```
class Reporting_Information:
""" ES0388F4  UCCI 130 Record (Reporting Information) """

fields = (
    ('Agreement_Number',13),
    ("Contract_ID",27),
    ('Record_Identifier',3),
    ('Sequence_Number',7),
    ('Report_Count',2),
    ('Report_Qualifier_Code',2),
    ('Report_Qualifier',0),
    ('Effective_Date',10),
    ('Report_ID',30),
    ('Report_Qualifier2',10),
    ('Cancel_Date',0),
    ('Filler',396)
    )

def __init__(self):
    self.Agreement_Number =''
    self.Contract_ID =''
    self.Record_Identifier ='130'
    self.Sequence_Number ='0'
    self.Report_Count ='01'
    self.Report_Qualifier_Code='LU'
    self.Report_Qualifier =''
    self.Effective_Date =''
    self.Report_ID =''
    self.Report_Qualifier2 =''
    self.Cancel_Date = ''
    self.Filler =''

def __str__(self):
  for field_name, width in self.fields:
    return ''.join([getattr(self, field_name).ljust(width)])

r = Reporting_Information()
r.Agreement_Number = dental_df['Agreement_Number'][0]
r1 = str(r)
print(r1)
```

Comment: As a hint, check what you get when you use `dental_df.iloc[0]`. Now you can write a function that takes that as an argument and creates a `Reporting_Information` object with corresponding data.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ljust' i get  this error after using dental_df.iloc[0]

Comment: I didn't mean to replace something in your code with `dental_df.iloc[0]`. I meant to look at what that expression gives you and work out  how to use it in your code.